# Plt Nameerror (name 'xxx' not defined) - Jupyter Notebook, Python 3.8.3

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to import a small CSV file in order to create a plot of an Expected Value, the count of observations and the mean expected value (Expected Value / Count).
However, plt does not seem to pick up the variables. To me it looks like there are headers, when I tried to run a 'for' through the columns I got the variable names back. Also, info() returns the names. Encoding-wise I tried 'utf_8 and 'latin1'.

The dataset is the following (copied the content from the CSV file):
[image: data]

Please see below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('pyplottest.csv', index_col=0, header=0, thousands = '.', decimal = ',',
                  na_values='', delimiter =';', encoding = 'latin1')

df
```

[image: Dataframe]

```
for col in df.columns: 
    print(col)
```

[image: for loop]

```
df.info()
```

[image: Info]

```
plt.plot(ExpectedValue, Count)
```

---

> NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> ----> 1 plt.plot(ExpectedValue, Count)
>
> NameError: name 'ExpectedValue' is not defined

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `plt.plot(df.ExpectedValue, df.Count)`

Comment: Or `df.plot(x='ExpectedValue', y='Count')`